# Properties transfer in soapui using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

[image]Is there any way that i can use groovy script to transfer values of properties from soap test case response to another soap test step? please find the response structure

```html
  <NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <NS1:Body>
  <NS2:processRequestResponse xmlns:NS2="http://bussinessfacade.fawryswitch.ebpp.fawryis.com/">
     <return>
        <Response>
           <SignonRs>
              <ClientDt>2016-04-19T16:58:12.141</ClientDt>
              <CustLangPref>ar-eg</CustLangPref>
              <ServerDt>2016-11-02T13:58:09</ServerDt>
              <Language>en-gb</Language>
              <SignonProfile>
                 <Sender>FAWRY</Sender>
                 <Receiver>FAWRYRTL</Receiver>
                 <MsgCode>BillInqRs</MsgCode>
                 <Version>V1.0</Version>
              </SignonProfile>
           </SignonRs>
           <PresSvcRs>
              <RqUID>0045d98c-e81c-43fd-b887-b0b1a1b1641d</RqUID>
              <AsyncRqUID>1a50b367-4aca-4d90-9f95-ddca99e8639d</AsyncRqUID>
              <MsgRqHdr>
                 <NetworkTrnInfo>
                    <OriginatorCode>FAWRYRTL</OriginatorCode>
                    <TerminalId>11427</TerminalId>
                 </NetworkTrnInfo>
              </MsgRqHdr>
              <Status>
                 <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
                 <Severity>Info</Severity>
                 <StatusDesc>Success.</StatusDesc>
              </Status>
              <BillInqRs>
                 <DeliveryMethod>POS</DeliveryMethod>
                 <BillRec>
                    <BillingAcct>0120000200</BillingAcct>
                    <BillTypeCode>111</BillTypeCode>
                    <BillRefNumber>2feeccae-8fd2-4d41-903a-df2ef96d5264</BillRefNumber>
                    <BillInfo>
                       <BillSummAmt>
                          <BillSummAmtCode>TotalAmtDue</BillSummAmtCode>
                          <CurAmt>
                             <Amt>370</Amt>
                             <CurCode>EGP</CurCode>
                          </CurAmt>
                       </BillSummAmt>
                       <IssueDt>2016-08-01</IssueDt>
                    </BillInfo>
                 </BillRec>
              </BillInqRs>
           </PresSvcRs>
        </Response>
     </return>
  </NS2:processRequestResponse>
   </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

ack.imgur.com/Z7UwT.png

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question with details? i.e., where the properties are ? how you want to use them?

Comment: the properties exist in soap test step response and want to transfer them to test suite level ( taking amount from response and add it to all other steps in same test case) the actual properties are Amt,AsyncRqUID & BillRefNumber

Comment: Sample structure of your response or raw response, please? And the retrieved value is used in other test step request, is that right?

Comment: Yes Rao iam using the retrieved values of theses properties in other test steps in same TC,                                                                                               for response structure i updated the question with screen shot of response structure

Comment: Response text would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the details, please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Script Assertion` for the same request step where the response is received. Can be avoided using separate `Groovy Script` step. So that check for the required values from the response before saving them as properties.

**Script Assertion:**

```
/**
* This is script assertion
* retrieves specified values from currest step response
* and stores at test case level
**/

//Closure to search the data
def searchData = { data, item ->
    data?.'**'.find { it.name() == item} as String
}
//Assert the response.
assert context.response, "Response is empty or null"

def parsedData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Get Amount
def amt = searchData(parsedData, 'Amt')
log.info "Amount from response: ${amt}"
//Check the value amt
assert amt, "Amount is empty or not present"
//Store Amount at test case level
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('AMOUNT', amt)


//Get AsyncRqUID
def rqUid = searchData(parsedData, 'AsyncRqUID')
log.info "AsyncRqUID from response: ${rqUid}"
//Check the value rqUid
assert rqUid, "AsyncRqUID is empty or not present"
//Store RqUid at test case level
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('AsyncRqUID', rqUid)
```

The above would fetch values `370` as amount and `1a50b367-4aca-4d90-9f95-ddca99e8639d` as AsyncRqUID.

In the other test request steps where you would require those retrieved values, please use as given below:

- For Amount (Amt), `${#TestCase#AMOUNT}`. Example `<amount>${#TestCase#AMOUNT}</amount>`
- For RqUID, `${#TestCase#AsyncRqUID}`. Example `<rquid>${#TestCase#AsyncRqUID}</rquid>`

Comment: the thing is i can't use it a test suite level as every test case has its AMOUNT & AsyncRqUID

Comment: Updated answer as per the comment, please re-check the answer.

Comment: Glad to know that the answer is helpful. Have great day.